# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client - But the code should not be running

Tags: node.js, express

So I am trying to set a session (which does set) however because the code on line 125 has this:

```
 res.set({
      "Content-Type": "audio/mpeg",
      'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
  });
```

It is causing the following error.

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client

The code that runs at the very start is

```
 if(!query.uuid && !req.session.uuid){
         tempuuid = uuidv4();
         req.session.uuid = tempuuid;
         res.redirect('/station'+req.url+'&uuid='+tempuuid);
         
      }
      
      if(!req.session.uuid){
        req.session.uuid = query.uuid;
        res.redirect('/station'+req.url+'&uuid='+query.uuid);
        
      }

      if(req.session.uuid){
        uuid = req.session.uuid;
      }
```

So My question is how do I stop the script from running further if the res.redirect has been triggered?

Comment: try to return res.redirect ...

Comment: add a return statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error generally occurs  because, your code is running after your desire statement or action .

try to return your statement  .
according to mozilla : [return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#:%7E:text=When%20a%20return%20statement%20is,where%20x%20is%20a%20number.&text=If%20the%20value%20is%20omitted%2C%20undefined%20is%20returned%20instead.)

**When a return statement is used in a function body, the execution of the function is stopped. If specified, a given value is returned to the function caller.**